# Nested ul display:none doesn't work in IE8

Tags: html, css

Using IE8 (Windows XP support), the following simple CSS selector does not achieve its goal of turning nested ul's to a display of none.  Rather, the entire list is displayed.  This code does work on IE9+ and all other modern browsers.  Is this a bug, or expected behavior?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsFiddle of above code here](http://jsfiddle.net/UdWEu/)

Comment: you want to see 4 links instead of 9 am I right?

Comment: Yes.  I will use additional hover rules to make the nested ul's appear.  (Ultimately a horizontal drop down menu).

Comment: What happens if you omit `nav` from the CSS rules?

Comment: Can you try your code outside a **nav** markup ?

Comment: Kay, this was the problem.  I foolishly forgot to load the html5shiv.js.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm new to s.o..  Can I close this question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because the css rule is invalid in IE8 as the `nav` element doesn't exist in that browser. The rule `ul li ul` works correctly.

Comment: One might mention that any sane browser does not care if the tag is known or not: http://jsfiddle.net/RVZhv/

Comment: @Kay True. IE is always a funny browser haha.

Answer (score 2):

@Pigueiras is correct. You need to include a script like Modernizr (or html5 shim) in order to style HTML5 semantic elements in IE <8.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a default IE8 behavior who does NOT understand html5 `<nav>` markup. You will have to force em in your layout.

You can add this to your document header

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
    document.createElement('nav');
    /* left part is not needed for your situation but an example for you */
    document.createElement('header');
    document.createElement('section');
    document.createElement('article');
    document.createElement('aside');
    document.createElement('footer');
    document.createElement('hgroup');
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Oups, i just read you answered yourself with the html5shiv.js in your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in IE7. Hope it helps.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
            <ul style="display:none;">
                <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul style="display:none;">
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At that point OP could drop the inner `<ul>`s altogether. ;-)

Comment: "Original poster", the personal who started a thread (i.e. asked the question). http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=OP